# How can I make TCP notify the UDP on the same port?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, udp

I have two main, TCPMain.java and UDPMain.java. when I run the TCPMain.java, TCPMain will run UDPMain.java

```
public class TCPMain{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UDPMain.main(args)
        //do sth
    } 
}
```

They listen to the same port and receive their respective messages or packet.

Then I have a situation that I need to notify UDP when TCP receives a specific message. When UDP was notified by TCP, UDP will send the packet to its client.

How can I make TCP notify the UDP on the same port?

Comment: `They listen to the same port and receive their respective messages or packet.` - No, they do not listen on the same port. UDP ports are completely separate from TCP ports.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do. It sounds like you want to simultaneously listen for data on both a TCP and UDP port simultaneously and sharing some processing code. Am I correct?  I'm not sure what you mean by "notify".

Comment: "notify" means letting UDPMain notice that TCP has received a specific message. They don't need to share value.

Comment: "They listen to the same port and receive their respective messages or packet." so that is why I put "respective" there. Because UDP will only deal with the datagramPacket and TCP is dealing with the socket sent with byte array with stream

Comment: My psychic powers suggest you at least two threads. One for TCP and another for UDP. Each time your TCP threads reads enough bytes from an incoming socket to be a complete message or when your UDP receives a message, you invoke some common processing code - perhaps with thread safe locks as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, I think I need to make a thread

Comment: *My* psychic powers say that you need to stop pretending the TCP and the UDP part are two completely separate programs. You need to write *one* program which does all the things you want it to do.